# Nesting Flask-SQLAlchemy relationship with Marshmallow

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I am using flask_marshmallow (0.10.1) to serialize the data from my flask_sqlalchemy tables into JSON objects.

However there is a relationship between the 2 tables (Post and Comments). I've done some research but I'm not sure how to use nesting or what to call to properly serialize into JSON.

Here are my flask_sqlalchemy classes:

```py
class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    comments = db.relationship('Comment',backref='post_owner') #This needs an integer to increment im

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Post({self.id}, {self.content}), {self.comments}"

class Comment(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    comment = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=True)
    owner_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('post.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Comment {self.comment}"
```

Then here are my flask_marshmallow schemas:

```py
class PostSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Post

class CommentSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
```

Lastly here is the function where I'm calling the schema to serialize:

```py
def convert_to_json(post_to_convert):  
    post_schema = PostSchema()
    output = post_schema.dump(post_to_convert)
    return output
```

The current output I get is this:

```
{id: 1, content: "Hello Again", comments: Array(3)} comments: (3) [1, 2, 3]
```

What I WANT to get (in comments:) is this:

```
{id: 1, content: "Hello Again", comments: Array(3)} comments: (3) ["first comment", "second comment", "third comment"]
```

I need the actual comment text data not just the Id numbers which is what I'm getting. Any help is appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily achieve that with a `Nested` field in your `PostSchema` (assuming you are using `marshmallow-sqlalchemy`) :

```
from marshmallow_sqlalchemy.fields import Nested

class PostSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
    comments = Nested(CommentSchema, many=True)

class CommentSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
```

I recommend you read [Marshmallow's documentation about Nesting schemas](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/nesting.html) to understand the different options and arguments.
Also, the documentation of [Marshmallow SQLAlchemy](https://marshmallow-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), particularly the "Recipes" section is helpful and give ideas on how to build schemas.

Comment: I got this error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'Nested' from 'marshmallow_sqlalchemy.fields'`

Comment: Depends if you are using `flask-marshmallow`, `marshmallow-sqlalchemy` or just `marshmallow`. Check where you can get this `Nested` field object on the documentation of the module you are using.

Comment: I was using flask-marshmallow but it makes no mention of Nested field object in the Docs. So I just switched to marshmallow_sqlalchemy. Here are my imports `from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
#from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
from marshmallow import fields
from marshmallow_sqlalchemy import ModelSchema
from marshmallow_sqlalchemy.fields import Nested`

Comment: There we go, you can see that `Nested` is part of the `fields` module. So you can use `fields.Nested()` without having to import anything. You should check how modules and packages are organized and imported in python: https://realpython.com/python-modules-packages/